# xdebug phpstorm docker linux

Tags: linux, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I can't catch any request with xdebug to my app.

xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=On
```

[image: Debug configuratin]

[image: PHP Settings]

[image: Server]

[image: Debug settings]

[image: DBGp Proxy]

Comment: Enable xdebug logging and check if xdebug connects to IDE using correct address & port: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs

Answer (score 2):

I see you've tagged this with "docker". If you use docker, you can't use `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`. You need to specify `xdebug.remote_host=IP-address-of-the-machine-as-reachable-by-docker-where-your-IDE-runs`. This *can* be `host.docker.internal` in newer versions.

In order to further debug networking issues, please also set `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` in your `php.ini` settings, and see what it says when you initiate a debugging session (through a browser extension).

Comment: I specified remote host as you say but executing still didn't stop at brakepoints.
I added logging to xdebug.
Here is output:

    `[32365] Log opened at 2020-02-18 13:49:03
     [32365] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 0.0.0.0:9000.
     [32365] I: Connected to client. :-)
     xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"> 
    </response>`

Comment: So i instantly got stopping state without any break/starting/running/stopped

Comment: `<init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/artisan" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.19" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14781" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.9.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>`

Comment: Looks like things work just fine on the Xdebug side then, and your issues are with your IDE.

Comment: i fixed it by `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT`
now it works

Answer (score 0):

fixed by `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT`
with following xdebug.ini config

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
#172.17.0.1 is docker0 interface ip address (see ifconfig)
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```